# use ssh-tunnel in multiple NestJS services with @nestjs/mongoose lib

Tags: typescript, mongoose, nestjs, ssh-tunnel

I have a NestJS project with 6 independent services using @nestjs/mongoose lib to connect a mongoDB, but the mongoDB has been changed to DocumentDB. I would like to connect to this database from my local environment. This is only feasible through SSH-tunnel, but I don't know how to use an SSH-tunnel with @nestJS/mongoose library, and use it in all the 6 independent services in the same time.

I tried to open an ssh-tunnel from command line, the MongoCompass could connect in this way (to the localhost address with given authentication), but NestJS throwed a time-out error, when the ssh-tunnel was opened in command line.

I use the mongoose connection in this way, as shown below:

```
//...
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      load: [bucketConfig, networkConfig],
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: config.get('DATABASE_URI'),
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        autoIndex: config.get('DATABASE_AUTO_INDEX', 'false'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
//...
```

Could anyone help me how to implement this connection issue?